# Microsoft Outlook 2007's feature in Outlook 2002?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, notifications

Few months back I used Outlook 2007's and I liked the mail notification feature which displays new mail notifications in the right corner of the desktop and fade out after few seconds. But now using Outlook 2002(XP) and that feature is missing in it .

Is there any plugin / software to emulate that feature ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Mail Alert](http://www.bettasoft.net/). It's not free, however it only costs $3.95. I'm using it in Outlook 2007 because you can also set it to notify you about any new mail that was moved to a folder by a rule.

> Mail Alert is an e-mail alert add-in for Microsoft Outlook 2000 / XP / 2003 / 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how it worked in Outlook 2002, but can't you create a rule that display a "Desktop Alert" when a new mail comes in?

If this doesn't work, maybe you'll be interested in the [Traylook Add-in for Outlook](http://www.pergenex.com/traylook/index.shtml) from Pergenex Software. It looks like it brings notifications more-or-less like the ones of Outlook 2007. But it isn't free.

> **Traylook Features**
>
> - Integrates directly with Outlook 2000/2002/2003. Traylook runs when
>   Outlook is active, there is no
>   additional programs to run or manage.
> - Traylook settings are configured conveniently within
>   Outlook's Options window.
> - Create your own colorful popup notification windows similar to MSN
>   popups.
> - Traylook's popup notification window can be configured to display
>   in multiple convenient locations on
>   your windows desktop.
> - Choose which folders you want Traylook to examine.
> - Hide Outlook from the taskbar and run invisibly in the
>   background.New Feature
> - User selectable sounds to accompany the notifications.
> - Automatic removal of Outlooks standard tray icon. This icon is
>   replaced with Traylook's more
>   informative icon.
> - New mail messages cycle automatically in popup windows
>   showing folder name, email From
>   field, and Subject field.
> - Email messages that were marked as important from the sender are
>   highlighted in red.
> - A new system tray icon is added which is color coded to reflect the
>   status of your inbox messages.
> - Read email directly by clicking links in the notification popup window.